# HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse throws a NotSupportedException in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-7, iasyncresult

in a Silverlight-Windows Phone 7-project I am creating an HttpWebRequest, get the RequestStream, write something into the Stream and try to get the response, but I always get a NotSupportedException: 
"System.Net.Browser.OHWRAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

My production code is far more complicated, but I can narrow it down to this small piece of code:

```
public class HttpUploadHelper
{
    private HttpWebRequest request;
    private RequestState state = new RequestState();

    public HttpUploadHelper(string url)
    {
        this.request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        state.Request = request;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        request.Method = "POST";
        this.request.BeginGetRequestStream(
            new AsyncCallback(BeginRequest), state);
    }

    private void BeginRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Stream stream = state.Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
        state.Request.BeginGetResponse(
            new AsyncCallback(BeginResponse), state);
    }

    private void BeginResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // BOOM: NotSupportedException was unhandled; 
        // {System.Net.Browser.OHWRAsyncResult}
        // AsyncWaitHandle = 'ar.AsyncWaitHandle' threw an 
        // exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
        HttpWebResponse response = state.Request.EndGetResponse(ar) as HttpWebResponse;
        Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    }
}

public class RequestState
{
    public WebRequest Request;
}
```

}

Does anybody know what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 22):

The `NotSupportedException` can be thrown when the request stream isn't closed before the call to `EndGetResponse`.  The WebRequest stream is still open and sending data to the server when you're attempting to get the response.  Since stream implements the `IDisposable` interface, a simple solution is to wrap your code using the request stream in a `using` block:

```
private void BeginRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    using (Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(ar))
    {
        //write to stream in here.
    }
    state.Request.BeginGetResponse(
        new AsyncCallback(BeginResponse), state);
}
```

The using block will ensure that the stream is closed before you attempt to get the response from the web server.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with how you're dealing with the accessing the original requests in the callback from `BeginGetResponse`.

Rather than holding a reference ot the state, get a reference back to the original request with:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
```

Have a look at this very basic (but working) example of implementing logging in by posting email and password credentials to a website.

```
public static string Email;

public static string Password;


private void LoginClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Email = enteredEmailAddress.Text.Trim().ToLower();

    Password = enteredPassword.Password;

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(App.Config.ServerUris.Login);

    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(ReadCallback, request);
}

private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

    using (var postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult))
    {
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var content = string.Format("Password={0}&Email={1}",
                                        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Password), 
                                        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Email));

            var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

            memStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            memStream.Position = 0;
            var tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
            memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);

            postStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        }
    }

    request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, request);
}

private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

    using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
    {
        using (var streamResponse = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse))
            {
                string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

                // do something with responseString to check if login was successful
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I am facing similar issue. Please help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598666/how-to-fix-system-argumentexception-in-httpwebresponse

Answer (score 1):

`NotSupportedException` can also be thrown when `string url` is too long. I had messed up and attached post data to url instead of post body. When the data was short, it worked just fine, but once it grew too large - `EndGetResponse` crashed.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
    state.Request.BeginGetResponse(
        new AsyncCallback(BeginResponse), state);
```

To this:

```
    state.Request.BeginGetResponse(BeginResponse, state);
```

Comment: Nah, "new AsyncCallback()" does nothing in this case, it can be omitted in general.