# HttpWebRequest(GET) works on emulator, doesn't work on device

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8.1

I'm writing a little game for windows phone. It puts scores of everyone to mysql database(using php) and gets the best score. Everything works fine on the emulator, unfortunately it does not work on the physical device.

Here's the code for getting the best score:

```
    public static void retrieveBestScore()
    {
      string uri = "https://xxxxxx.net/get_scores.php?sort=score%20DESC&count=1";
      HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
      request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), request);
    }

    private static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        [...]
    }
```

ReadCallBack method if fired, but asynchronousResult's AsyncWaitHandle parameter is

> base = {System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not
>   supported.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.OHWRAsyncResult.get_AsyncWaitHandle()}

I've read somewhere the problem may be caused by using https instead of http, but it's not the case here.

Comment: Do you have the `Internet (Client & Server)` Capability on in your app manifest?

Comment: I do have Networking capability checked. As I said- everything works great on emulator.

Comment: Using your code, I can get the `HttpWebRequest request` without a crash. Have you tried it in a new SL app?

Comment: I just did with the same result. Are sure you tested it on a device?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure :) What version of windows are you targeting? My test project is WP8.1. And I think i'm using a SilverLight app, but I can't find it in VS.

Comment: I've tested it on 8.0 wp, my original project is targetting monogame 8.0 :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not supported exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166222/httpwebrequest-endgetresponse-throws-a-notsupportedexception-in-windows-phone-7)